# Squared variable omitted in estimation of Prais-Winsten and Cochrane-Orcutt

Tags: autocorrelation, stata, multicollinearity

I have estimated a model with OLS, where I have found autocorrelation with Durbin-Watson and Breusch-Godfrey. I want to use Prais-Winsten or Cochrane-Orcutt to remove the problem. When estimating the model, it removes a variable, which is a squared variable of another variable in the model.

I use the following code:

```
gen yearsquared=year*year
```

For OLS:

```
reg ftheft tfr partic degrees year yearsquared
```

For Cochrane-Orcutt:

```
prais ftheft tfr partic degrees year yearsquared, corc
```

For Prais-Winston:

```
prais ftheft tft partic degrees year yearsquared
```

In both cases, `yearsquared` gets removed from Stata.

Any advice, as `yearsquared` shouldn`t be removed due to collinearity?

Comment: Please use capital letters and punctuation where appropriate.

Comment: Cross-posted and discussed at length at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1586529-squared-variable-omitted-in-estimation-of-prais-winsten-and-cochrane-orcutt Telling people about cross-posting elsewhere is always a good idea.